# set Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore on tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl

I'm trying config a secure connection whit a vendor, the problem is that I can't config tomcat properly. Example:

I run a simple java client with the JVM arguments

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=/home/pablo/keystore.jks
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=password
```

and everything works fine.

Then I try to do the same whit tomcat, so I put the same arguments to the JAVA_OPT variable in catalina.sh. But doesn't work.

May be the problem is here:

```
http-bio-8080-exec-1, READ: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 4
*** ServerHelloDone
Warning: no suitable certificate found - continuing without client authentication
*** Certificate chain
<Empty>
***
```

The tomcat proccess run like this

```
/usr/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/home/log/apache-tomcat-7.0.88/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager-Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048 -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=/home/pablo/keyStorePim.jks -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=password -Xdebug -Xnoagent -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=4040,server=y,suspend=n -Djavax.net.debug=ssl -Dignore.endorsed.dirs= -classpath /home/pablo/apache-tomcat-7.0.88/bin/bootstrap.jar:/home/pablo/apache-tomcat-7.0.88/bin/tomcat-juli.jar -Dcatalina.base=/home/pablo/apache-tomcat-7.0.88 -Dcatalina.home=/home/pablo/apache-tomcat-7.0.88 -Djava.io.tmpdir=/home/pablo/apache-tomcat-7.0.88/temp org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start
```

Java version:

```
java version "1.8.0_171"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_171-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.171-b11, mixed mode)
```

Tomcat Version:

```
Server version: Apache Tomcat/7.0.88
Server built:   May 7 2018 11:12:57 UTC
Server number:  7.0.88.0
OS Name:        Linux
OS Version:     4.13.0-39-generic
Architecture:   amd64
JVM Version:    1.8.0_171-b11
JVM Vendor:     Oracle Corporation
```

Comment: Have you added your certificate to the keystore?

Comment: Keystore is normally set in server.xml, generally for purpose of setting up HTTPS.  I suspect that is what is overriding your settings.  See [link](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/ssl-howto.html#Edit_the_Tomcat_Configuration_File) for more details.

Comment: @Alfabravo, yes the cert is in the key store, in the first example (simple java client) and in the second one i'm using the same keystore

Comment: @user3745362, I understand that you said. I'll investigate a little bit over that...

Comment: @user3745362: server.xml sets SSL/TLS parameters including keystore (in 8.5 up possibly multiple keystores) _for the Connector(s)_ which handle _incoming_ connections from clients like browsers. It does not handle or override _outgoing_ connections '[with] a vendor' as in this Q. pablo: probably useless now, but since you had the debuglog, just before the '*** ServerHelloDone' you posted there should have been a '*** CertificateRequest' block with useful information, and much earlier (maybe a hundred lines or more) it should have shown loading the keymanager, also useful.